# Need to extend the validity (number of days) for an unused Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-extensions

I applied for a Schengen visa at the Swiss embassy and they gave me exactly 10 days for the dates of the application I submitted.

My husband (he's holding an american passport so he doesn't require any visa) now decides to extend our honeymoon for one more week.

They advised me to resubmit our application with the updated requirements (itineraries, tickets, etc.) They will have to cancel my original visa and issue another one (after evaluation).

Has anyone had a similar situation?

More info: I already have a previous Schengen visa with multiple entry and valid for 30 days stay.

Comment: "They advised me".  Who is 'they'?

Answer (score 2):

I have not personally been in this situation and I don't know anybody who has but the advice you were given does make sense in light of all the relevant regulations. There are no provision that would allow you to get your visa amended easily. The only situation in which you are entitled to an extension is when you are already in the Schengen area and unable to leave because of *force majeure* or humanitarian reasons (i.e. not merely because you changed your mind and wish to stay longer).

If the trip is similar and all the documents are in order, I would not expect any issue with your new application but they will charge you €60 for the pleasure, although they could probably waive the fee if they wished (cancelling a visa and issuing a new one free of charge is in effect what consulates do when *they* make a mistake). Having used an earlier visa correctly should certainly help your application in any case.